# libgdx not smooth movement small screen resolution

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a simple game and faced with a problem. On devices with screen resolution that is lower, than game world resolution, movement is not smooth and looks very disgusting.

My code:

```
public float LAST_GROUND_LEVEL, CURRENT_GROUND_LEVEL, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS;
public int CURRENT_GROUND_INDEX, COUNTER_TO_NEXT_PLANK = 0;

private Ball ball;
private Array<Plank> planks;
private Array<GroundPlank> groundPlanks;

private Random random;

public PlayState(GameStateManager gsm) {
    super(gsm);
    orthographicCamera.setToOrtho(false, JumpingBall.WIDTH, JumpingBall.HEIGHT);
    ball = new Ball(JumpingBall.WIDTH / 2, JumpingBall.HEIGHT / 2, gameStateManager);

    planks = new Array<Plank>();

    random = new Random();
    groundPlanks = new Array<GroundPlank>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        if (i != 2) {
            groundPlanks.add(new GroundPlank(i * orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, 600 * JumpingBall.RATIO, orthographicCamera));
            CURRENT_GROUND_INDEX = i;
            CURRENT_GROUND_LEVEL = 600 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
        } else {
            boolean side = random.nextBoolean();
            if (side == true) {
                groundPlanks.add(new GroundPlank(i * orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, 800 * JumpingBall.RATIO, orthographicCamera));
                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = 800 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
            } else {
                groundPlanks.add(new GroundPlank(i * orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, 400 * JumpingBall.RATIO, orthographicCamera));
                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = 400 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
            }
        }
        LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS = LAST_GROUND_LEVEL;
        COUNTER_TO_NEXT_PLANK++;
    }
}

@Override
public void handleInput() {
    if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
        ball.jump();
    }
}

@Override
public void update(float delta) {
    if (delta > 0f) {
        handleInput();
        for (int i = 0; i < groundPlanks.size; i++) {
            if ((ball.getPosition().x + ball.getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO / 2 > groundPlanks.get(i).getPosition().x) &(ball.getPosition().x + ball.getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO / 2 < groundPlanks.get(i).getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2))
            {
                ball.update(delta, CURRENT_GROUND_LEVEL + groundPlanks.get(0).getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO, groundPlanks.get(i).getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, CURRENT_GROUND_LEVEL + groundPlanks.get(0).getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL + groundPlanks.get(0).getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
            }
        }
        orthographicCamera.position.x = ball.getPosition().x + ball.getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO / 2;

        boolean foundPlank = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < groundPlanks.size; i++) {
            if (foundPlank == false) {
                GroundPlank groundPlank = groundPlanks.get(i);
                GroundPlank RepositionPlank;

                if ((orthographicCamera.position.x > groundPlank.getPosition().x) & ((groundPlank.getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2) > orthographicCamera.position.x)) {
                    CURRENT_GROUND_LEVEL = groundPlank.getPosition().y;
                    if (i > 1) {
                        RepositionPlank = groundPlanks.get(0);
                    } else if (i == 1) {
                        RepositionPlank = groundPlanks.get(2);
                    } else {
                        RepositionPlank = groundPlanks.get(1);
                    }
                    if (i != CURRENT_GROUND_INDEX) {
                        boolean side = random.nextBoolean();
                        if (side == true) {
                            if (LAST_GROUND_LEVEL < GroundPlank.HIGHEST_OPENING) {
                                RepositionPlank.Reposition(groundPlank.getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL + 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
                                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = LAST_GROUND_LEVEL + 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
                            } else {
                                RepositionPlank.Reposition(groundPlank.getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL - 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
                                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = LAST_GROUND_LEVEL - 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (LAST_GROUND_LEVEL > GroundPlank.LOWEST_OPENING) {
                                RepositionPlank.Reposition(groundPlank.getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL - 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
                                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = LAST_GROUND_LEVEL - 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
                            } else {
                                RepositionPlank.Reposition(groundPlank.getPosition().x + orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL + 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
                                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL = LAST_GROUND_LEVEL + 200 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
                            }
                        }
                        CURRENT_GROUND_INDEX = i;

                        for (int j = 0; j < groundPlanks.size; j++) {
                            if (orthographicCamera.position.x < groundPlanks.get(j).getPosition().x) {
                                LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS = groundPlanks.get(j).getPosition().y;
                            }
                        }

                        COUNTER_TO_NEXT_PLANK++;
                        if (COUNTER_TO_NEXT_PLANK == 4) {
                            if (planks.size != 0) {
                                Plank plank = planks.get(0);
                                plank.reposition(RepositionPlank.getPosition().x, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS + 20 * JumpingBall.RATIO + RepositionPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO, RepositionPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO + LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS + 150 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
                            } else {
                                planks.add(new Plank(RepositionPlank.getPosition().x, LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS + 20 * JumpingBall.RATIO + RepositionPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO, RepositionPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() / 4 * JumpingBall.RATIO + LAST_GROUND_LEVEL_PLANKS + 150 * JumpingBall.RATIO));
                            }
                            COUNTER_TO_NEXT_PLANK = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    foundPlank = true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (planks.size != 0){
            if (planks.get(0).Collides(ball.getBounds())){
                gameStateManager.set(new MenuState(gameStateManager));
            }
        }
    }
    orthographicCamera.update();
}

@Override
public void render(SpriteBatch spriteBatch) {
    spriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(orthographicCamera.combined);
    spriteBatch.begin();
    spriteBatch.draw(ball.getBall(), ball.getPosition().x, ball.getPosition().y, ball.getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO, ball.getBall().getHeight() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO);
    for (Plank plank : planks) {
        spriteBatch.draw(plank.getPlank(), plank.getPosTopPlank().x, plank.getPosTopPlank().y, plank.getPlank().getWidth() * JumpingBall.RATIO / 4, plank.getPlank().getHeight() * JumpingBall.RATIO);
        spriteBatch.draw(plank.getPlank(), plank.getPosBotPlank().x, plank.getPosBotPlank().y, plank.getPlank().getWidth() * JumpingBall.RATIO / 4, plank.getPlank().getHeight() * JumpingBall.RATIO);
    }
    for (GroundPlank groundPlank : groundPlanks) {
        spriteBatch.draw(groundPlank.getGroundPlankTexture(), groundPlank.getPosition().x, groundPlank.getPosition().y, orthographicCamera.viewportWidth / 2, groundPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().getHeight() * JumpingBall.RATIO / 4);
    }
    spriteBatch.end();
}


@Override
public void dispose() {
    for (Plank plank : planks) {
        plank.dispose();
    }
    ball.getBall().dispose();
    for (GroundPlank groundPlank : groundPlanks) {
        groundPlank.getGroundPlankTexture().dispose();
    }
}
```

EDITED:

```
public void update(float delta, float groundlevel, float cur_x_end, float cur_y, float next_y){
    GROUND_LEVEL = groundlevel;
    if (position.y > GROUND_LEVEL){
        velocity.add(0, GRAVITY, 0);
    }
    velocity.scl(delta);
    position.add(MOVEMENT * delta, velocity.y, 0);
    if ((position.y <= GROUND_LEVEL) & (position.x + getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO < cur_x_end)){
        if (Down == false) {
            position.y = GROUND_LEVEL;
        }
    } else if (position.x + getBall().getWidth() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO > cur_x_end){
        if (next_y > cur_y){
            if (position.y < next_y){
                Down = true;
            }
        }
    }
    if (position.y + getBall().getHeight() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO < 0){
        gameStateManager.set(new MenuState(gameStateManager));
    }
    if (position.y >= JumpingBall.WORLD_HEIGHT * JumpingBall.RATIO - BallTexture.getHeight() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO){
        position.y = JumpingBall.WORLD_HEIGHT * JumpingBall.RATIO - BallTexture.getHeight() / 30 * JumpingBall.RATIO;
    }
    velocity.scl(1/delta);
    bounds.setPosition(position.x, position.y);
}
```

Comment: Is it a framerate issue? What do you mean by 'disgusting'?
Can you post the update method from the Ball class?

Comment: I updated the post. By disgusting I mean that textures are moving jerkily. It is not a framerate issue because fps is > 56 all the time

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It could be that you are moving the ball at an average of uneven pixels. If you move at a average speed of 1.6 pixels pr. frame, the ball will move 1 pixel some frames and 2 pixels other frames. This will result in stuttering.

There are no half pixels so you should make sure your speed makes the ball move the same number of pixel each frame.

Comment: Thanks! It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Please use scene2d for smooth movement and rotation.
[Read wiki page for implementation](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Scene2d)